# More than 4 billion key value pairs in Redis?

Tags: redis

I am trying to store ip numbers in redis along with associated ISP information. I have Maxmind data and the csv files contain start and end numbers for each ISP.

When querying in SQL I can check for an IP(after converting it to a number) to be available in a range and get the associated ISP.

I was thinking of converting all the ranges to individual numbers and submit all the key values pairs in Redis for faster lookup.
This approximately will result in 4 billion key value pairs in the Redis store.
I have done this for a few hundred million key value pairs but I am looking for advice/suggestions when moving to 4 billion pairs in Redis.
Any performance issues I must be aware of or are there ways I can do this better ?

Thank you for all the suggestions.

UPDATE: Thanks to the suggestions below I could get this working.
Thought I'd share the Python code (quick and dirty) for this here :

```
import redis
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='user',passwd='password',db='foo')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select startipnum,endipnum,isp from wiki.ipisp order by endipnum;')
result = cur.fetchall()

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
ispctr = 1
for row in result:
    tempDict = {'ispname':row[2],'fromval':row[0],'toval':row[1]}
    namefield = ispctr
    r.hmset(namefield,tempDict)
    r.zadd('ispmaxindex',row[1],namefield)
    ispctr = ispctr+1
conn.close()

ipstotest = ['23.23.23.23','24.96.185.10','203.59.91.235','188.66.105.50','99.98.163.93']
for ip in ipstotest:
    ipvalsList = [int(ipoct) for ipoct in ip.split('.')]
    ipnum = (16777216*ipvalsList[0]) + (65536*ipvalsList[1]) + (256*ipvalsList[2]) + ipvalsList[3]
    ipnum = long(ipnum)
    tempVal1 = r.zrangebyscore('ispmaxindex',ipnum,float('Inf'),0,1)
    tempval2 = r.hgetall(tempval1[0])
    print tempval2['ispname']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store 4B items in Redis with no specific degradation of performance, but you need the memory for this (i.e. everything must fit in memory).

The optimal ways to implement this kind of queries with Redis has been described here:

[store ip ranges in Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989023/store-ip-ranges-in-redis/9991303#9991303)

and here:

[Redis or Mongo for determining if a number falls within ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622816/redis-or-mongo-for-determining-if-a-number-falls-within-ranges/8624231#8624231)

So the complexity of the optimal solution depends on the fact you consider the ranges of IPs can overlap or not.

Comment: Really helpful links. Will explore these more. Thank you Didier.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's the wrong way to do it.

Keep IP mapping as integer ranges (From IP - To IP, [converted to decimal](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/IP2Integer.jsp)) and quickly query your subject IP using a traditional DB or using a NoSQL that's strong at comparisons.

Comment: That is what I have from maxmind, the ranges from and to for the IP converted to decimal. I tried MySQL and it seems slow for range queries which is why I thought a key value lookup will be faster/more efficient. Also I want to lookup in real time (all ips in the last 5 minutes ~ 5000+ IPs) when I am monitoring IP(s) hitting my website

Comment: Depending on your site's usage profile, you can cache matches in Redis (in addition to what I suggested). That is - once you find a from-to match to a given IP, save it in Redis. If your usage profile consists of frequent returning visitors, or visitors from the same region, this limited-size cache will give you great performance without getting into Redis memory size issues.

Comment: Ofer..thats bang on target. This is what I am doing right now and incrementally adding to my Redis store based on visitors above a frequency threshold. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [geodis](https://github.com/doat/geodis). It already does IP to country/location lookups and efficiently store those data for you. You are free to use it only for data loading and request data directly from redis itself.

Answer (score 2):

The approach we use for fast Geo-IP resolution is take all the IP ranges and break them at the `/24` (the first three quads), and store a record holding all the matches in those addresses. This gives you 16 million keys and O(1) access. If you'll tolerate the client-side complexity of breaking up the stored record, it's performant without taking up lots of RAM.

In more detail:

- take all ranges, and break them by their first 24 bits.

  - The range `128.100.60.0-128.100.60.9` becomes one record, `<128.100.60 | 0 9 | (...recA...)>`
  - The range `128.100.60.10 - 128.100.62.80` would become `<128.100.60 | 10 255 | (...recB...)>`, `<128.100.61 | 0 255 | (...recB...)>`, and `<128.100.62 | 0 80 | (...recB...)>`.
- combine all the records with the same prefix into a hash whose key is the *top* of its range. So

  - key `128.100.60`: `{9: {...recA...}, 255: {...recB...}}`
  - key `128.100.61`: `{255: {...recB...}}`
  - key `128.100.62`: `{80: {...recB...}, ...}`

To retrieve a specific IP, retrieve the compound record by its 24-bit key, and return the first result whose sub-key is larger than the last part.  If I looked up `128.100.60.20`, I would find that `9` was not larger, but that `255` was, and so return `recB`.

This is a common strategy for doing range joins (even spatial joins!) in things like Hadoop: partition on some reasonable chunk, and then index on one end of the range.